# Corsair Void Pro Wireless Firmware and Drivers not allowing Surround Sound

Tags: audio, drivers, firmware, headset, corsair

I have a Corsair Void Pro Wireless gaming headset.

However, during the firmware update to v0.15 of the headset and dongle, the equalizer, 8-channel surround sound, and the audio repositioning feature don't have any effect.

I also upgraded to Windows 11 at around the same time, but the problem still occurred when I temporarily downgraded to Windows 10 again. Also, Windows Spatial Sound is disabled, so that's definitely not the issue.

What I have already tried:

- re-installing iCUE,
- downgrading iCUE from v4 to v3,
- temporarily downgrading to Windows 10,
- reinstalling the original firmware which came with my headset,
- looking for other previous firmware.

When reinstalling the original firmware that came with the headset, it didn't work at all so I had to upgrade back to v0.15. (I had to use CorsairHeadsetFirmwareUpdate.exe to downgrade it since iCUE said the firmware files were invalid, even though that was what I had installed onto the headset using iCUE when I first bought it.)

Anyhow, are there any available links to previous firmware for the headset (I couldn't find any on corsair.com or archive.org), or is there another way to fix these problems.

Thanks for any help in advance.